# What is the meaning of jquery var objUl = $('ul', $dcDrilldownObj)

Tags: jquery

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#">menu 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">menu 1i</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">menu 1i i</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">menu 1i ii</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">menu 1ii</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">menu 1ii i</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">menu 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">menu 1i</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">menu 1i i</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">menu 1i ii</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">menu 1ii</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">menu 1i i</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">menu 1i ii</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>    
  <li><a href="#">menu 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">menu 1i</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">menu 1i i</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">menu 1ii</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">menu 1i i</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>      
  </li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function($){
    $('#menu').mobileMenu({
            saveState       : true,
            easing          : 'easeOutCirc'
    }); 
});

//  inside the plugin
return this.each(function (options) {
    var $dcDrilldownObj = this;
...

// Get height of largest sub menu
var objUl = $('ul', $dcDrilldownObj);
var maxItems = methods.findMaxHeight(objUl);
```

Above code is belongs to jquery menu plugin, HTML, and initiate the plugin, then inside get the object to veriable.

Here I have a doubt what is the meaning of

**var objUl = $('ul', $dcDrilldownObj);**

Could you please someone brief me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second argument in jQuery `$()` function means a "*context*" part (i.e. *where to search*). In your example you select all `<ul>` elements inside `$dcDrilldownObj`.

You can easily replace it with:

```
var objUl = $($dcDrilldownObj).find("ul");
```

You can read about `jQuery()` function here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1.

Answer (score 2):

The second argument is the context which in your case is `$('#menu')`

```
var objUl = $('ul', $dcDrilldownObj);
```

The above will return all `ul` elements inside `#menu` and set it to `objUl`